# JsonResult Response from WebAPI for Elasticsearch NEST query

Tags: elasticsearch, asp.net-web-api, nest, elasticsearch-5

I have created WEBAPI methods, to search ES using NEST. The search with ES is working as expected. The issue that I have is when I try to return the Json(response) using POSTMAN, it throws this exception:

> {
>       "Message": "An error has occurred.",
>       "ExceptionMessage": "If you use a custom contract resolver be sure to subclass from ElasticContractResolver",
>       "ExceptionType": "System.Exception",
>       "StackTrace": "   at Nest.JsonExtensions.GetConnectionSettings(JsonSerializer
>   serializer)\r\n   at
>   Nest.VerbatimDictionaryKeysJsonConverter`2.WriteJson(JsonWriter
>   writer, Object value, JsonSerializer serializer)\r\n   at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeConvertable(JsonWriter
>   writer, JsonConverter converter, Object value, JsonContract contract,
>   JsonContainerContract collectionContract, JsonProperty
>   containerProperty)\r\n   at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeValue(JsonWriter
>   writer, Object value, JsonContract valueContract, JsonProperty member,
>   JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty
>   containerProperty)\r\n   at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeObject(JsonWriter
>   writer, Object value, JsonObjectContract contract, JsonProperty
>   member, JsonContainerContract collectionContract, JsonProperty
>   containerProperty)\r\n   at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeValue(JsonWriter
>   writer, Object value, JsonContract valueContract, JsonProperty member,
>   JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty
>   containerProperty)\r\n   at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.Serialize(JsonWriter
>   jsonWriter, Object value, Type objectType)\r\n   at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.SerializeInternal(JsonWriter
>   jsonWriter, Object value, Type objectType)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Http.Results.JsonResult`1.Serialize()\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Http.Results.JsonResult`1.Execute()\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Http.Results.JsonResult`1.ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken
>   cancellationToken)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionInvoker.d__0.MoveNext()\r\n---
>   End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
>   ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.d__2.MoveNext()\r\n---
>   End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
>   ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Http.Controllers.AuthenticationFilterResult.d__0.MoveNext()\r\n---
>   End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
>   ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.d__1.MoveNext()"
>   }

This is my WEB API method

```
[System.Web.Http.Route("SearchElastic")]
[System.Web.Http.HttpPost]

public JsonResult<ISearchResponse<T>> SearchElastic([FromBody] ElasticSearchRequest esRequest)
{
    var searchResponse = EsClient.Search<T>(
        "...NEST query..."
                ));

    return Json(searchResponse);
}

//<T> is a custom C# class.
```

I am using Elasticsearch/NEST 5.x.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message hints at what the problem is

> { "Message": "An error has occurred.", "ExceptionMessage": "If you use
>   a custom contract resolver be sure to subclass from
>   ElasticContractResolver", "ExceptionType": "System.Exception",
>   "StackTrace": " at ...

and it relates to the line

```
    return Json(searchResponse);
```

the configuration for the Json serializer used by Web API does not know how to handle serializing certain types from NEST because some of those types need `ElasticContractResolver` to be serialized correctly.

There are a few ways to solve this, but the two most straightforward are:

1. Configure the Json Serializer used by Web API with `ElasticContractResolver` as the `IContractResolver` on the [`JsonSerializerSettings`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonSerializerSettings.htm). The disadvantage here is that all of your types that you're serializing to json will be going through NEST's resolver
2. Avoid the deserialization/re-serialization loop from Elasticsearch -> deserialized by NEST -> reserialized by Web API altogether by using the low level client to return a string or byte array from Elasticsearch. I would recommend this approach if you are not doing any introspection on `searchResponse`. If you do need to inspect `searchResponse`, you can always deserialize the string or byte array to `SearchResponse<T>` as a separate step.

This is one of the reasons that the [direct dependency on Json.NET has been removed in NEST 6.x](https://www.elastic.co/blog/nest-elasticsearch-net-6-0-ga)

Comment: Thanks Russ. For #1). Can you please point me to an example how this can be implemented, and #2) Do you mean, I should use Elastic.Net instead of NEST?